# Given a Google Drive File Link, how do I locate the link of the folder it resides in?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive

as above. It is just an unlisted folder, without access rights assigned (i.e. anyone can visit if you have the link).

Comment: Try the ideas in this article:   https://gsuitetips.com/tips/drive/add-google-drive-to-file-explorer-in-windows-10/#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20Google%20Drive%20File%20Stream%20%28G%3A%29,available%20offline%20unless%20you%20choose%20to%20download%20them.

Comment: The folder it resides within inside its Google Drive account, or on a host of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of Google Drive shared links is they are non-hierarchical, precisely so you can't climb out of the box you're put in.
If it was trivial to get access to the enclosing folder, the entire business model would fail.